# Disabled date field on node form stops it from saving

Tags: entities

I have a date field on a drupal node edit form using the pop-up calendar widget. When certain things happen on my site I have to disable some fields on that node edit form, including the date.

However, when this happens, I can no longer save the form because I get this message:

> The value input for field [my field] is invalid.

I tried changing the widget to plain text, and it works fine, so it is an issue with the pop-up calendar widget.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you disabling the form element?

Comment: In a form_alter hook:  $form[$field_id]['#disabled'] = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using `hook_form_alter` you can use **`#limit_validation_errors`** to exclude that field from validation.

> The #limit_validation_errors property is a list of "sections" within
>   $form_state['values'] that must contain valid values. Each "section"
>   is an array with the ordered set of keys needed to reach that part of
>   $form_state['values'] (i.e., the #parents property of the element).

**Example 1:** Allow the "Previous" button to function, regardless of whether any user input is valid.

```
  $form['actions']['previous'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Previous'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),       // No validation.
    '#submit' => array('some_submit_function'),  // #submit required.
  );
```

**Example 2:** Require some, but not all, user input to be valid to process the submission of a "Previous" button.

```
  $form['actions']['previous'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Previous'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(
      array('step1'),       // Validate $form_state['values']['step1'].
      array('foo', 'bar'),  // Validate $form_state['values']['foo']['bar'].
    ),
    '#submit' => array('some_submit_function'), // #submit required.
  );
```

**More info:** [`form_set_error`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7)